# Using the word repeat to go out with someone

Tags: word-meaning

I went out with someone and I would like to say that we should definitely repeat that, but repeat sound so technical to me, somehow. That's what I would write

> It was fun. We should definitely repeat that.

or with the usage of again.

> It was fun. We should definitely do this again.

Comment: FWIW, I see nothing wrong with saying either one. I disagree with the answer that you accepted. Using *repeat* is not particularly awkward or formal. And the rest of that answer, about *first date* and the addition of *sometime*, is also misguided, IMO.

Comment: @Drew I marked the answer as accepted, because it got several upvotes and it was obviously the only one. What do you mean by _misguided_?

Comment: You are of course free to accept any answer - I didn't mean to suggest that you should not. I disagree with the answer, not with your accepting it. I disagree that "*repeat* sounds awkwardly formal" here. And adding *sometime* is not more appropriate on a first date than on the 100th, IMO. And both *it* and *this* have the same need to refer to something. Anyway, it is no big deal - I didn't mean to suggest otherwise. The main point is that each of your sentences is fine, IMO. There is nothing wrong with using *repeat*, and it is not formal or awkward, IMHO. But opinions clearly vary. ;-)

Comment: @Drew - When my kids get off the roller coaster, they say, "Let's do that again!" not, "Let's repeat that ride." Similarly, if I've enjoyed a new restaurant with my wife, we don't say, "We should repeat this dining experience," we say, "We should come back again sometime." I only used the first date scenario because of the way the O.P. began the question. I never meant to imply that "sometime" is appropriate for a first date, but not the second or tenth; it simply means "at some unspecified time." I could also say, "We should come back Monday," but I wouldn't say, "Let's repeat this Monday."

Comment: @J.R.: So what? English, including informal English with or among kids, is not limited to just one or two formulas. You might never use the word *repeat* in such contexts, or in any context at all, for that matter. That does not make it awkward or formal to use it in such contexts. That just does not follow. Other people - plenty of them, do use it. And other kids do say "*Let's repeat that*", in addition to "*Let's do that again.*"  Like adults, kids are not limited to a single expression.

Comment: @Drew - As you say, opinions vary. Just because an answer has been "accepted" doesn't mean there isn't room for a counter-opinion. I completely agree that English isn't limited to one or two formulae, and my samples are meant to be general examples, not fixed expressions that shouldn't be changed (we'd all sound like robots if we  said the same few expressions over and over again). That said, in the context of a date, "Let's repeat this" sounds a bit unnatural to me, at least, less fluid than something like "Let's do that again" or "We should try this some other time" or many other variants.

Comment: @J.R. I think we generally agree. Let me just say that I have absolutely no problem with your having answered as you did or with your answer being accepted. I have only said that I disagree with your answer.

Comment: @Drew - I just did an interesting experiment: I did a search on Google books for the phrases `"Let's repeat this"` and `"Let's do this again"`. Space doesn't permit me to do a full report of the results, but the "repeat" version was linked to the likes of "let's repeat this _experiment/calculation/procedure_," while "let's do this again" was seen in more casual conversations, like, _“Let's do this again in a few days!”_ I don't think "repeat" is wrong grammatically, but the O.P. seems to think there might be more natural, casual ways to say what (s)he's trying to say – and I happen to agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hunch is correct. In this context, "repeat" sounds awkwardly formal.

Also, the wording of the first sentence depends on who initiates the conversation. If I'm on a first date, I would probably say something along the lines of:

> This was fun. We should do this again sometime.

However, if my date first said, "This was fun," then I might answer:

> Yes, it was fun. We should do this again.

So, whether you should use "it" or "this" depends on if whatever "it" refers to has been mentioned already in the conversation.

Although there's nothing grammatically wrong with *repeat*, it tends to be used in more formal contexts. It would be hard to find a scene in a romance movie where, after an especially nice date, one character says to the other:

> I had such a nice time; we should repeat this.

or any other similar quote using the word *repeat*. However, you might see the word *repeat* used on a cooking show, or hear it in a science class. It's more likely to be used when discussing formal *procedures*, rather than emotional *experiences* – at least, when I look up "we should repeat this" on [Google books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22we+should+repeat+this%22&lr=lang_en&safe=off&biw=1300&bih=852&source=lnt&tbs=lr&tbm=bks), I find references to meditation books and formal documents. But when I change the search terms to "we should do this again", that's when I find many excerpts such as:

> I grabbed a piece of paper and a pen. “Here is my number call me and we should do this again.”
>
> “Tonight was fun wouldn't you say, we should do this again sometime.”
>
> “I think we should do this again sometime, Tillie.”
> “I'd like that, Sam. I really would. It was a lovely dinner.”

Answer (score 2):

It sounds strange to use *repeat* in this context because it is a strange thing to say when you unpack the semantics.

When we say *we should do this [or it] again*, the pronoun means *go out*. This is not a specific activity; seeing a movie, having dinner or taking a walk are all things you might do if you *went out* with someone.

*Repeat* means *do essentially the same thing again*. If you *repeat* the evening, you are doing the same activities as before: seeing the same movie, eating at the same restaurant, or walking the same path at the same time. There will doubtless be some trivial differences, but *repeating* the experience will probably be quite boring, if not outright impossible to do.

And that's the heart of the issue. You're inviting someone to once more go out and have a fun time with you, not duplicate the previous experience. *Go out* is simply too nebulous a term to sensibly use *repeat* with in this context.